# Extract only sun tar.gz/zip

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, zip

I have a zip/tar.gz that contain zip files that contains another zip file.

For example:

```
1.zip contains 2.tar.gz and 3.zip.
3.zip contains 4.zip.
```

I want to extract only 4.zip from 1.zip, I don't want to extract all of files.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have `zip` archives or `tar` archives? You mention both on the first line.

Comment: Zip that contain zip and tar.gz

Comment: Do you mean that you need to extract `4.zip` without extracting `3.zip` first?
From your writing it seems that '4.zip` is compressed inside `3.zip`, which is compressed inside `1.zip`.
`1.zip` "is not aware" of `4.zip`, so it wouldn't be actually possible to extract it directly. Is it what you are asking?

Comment: Yes,you right ...

Comment: Could you make it clear on your question that `3.zip` cannot be extracted in the process? You mention that you do not want to extract everything, but extracting `3.zip` first and then `4.zip` would meet that requirement and doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you edit question to explain: What is sun? And respond to comments by editing your question. You can comment to say that you did it.

Answer (score 1):

This is harder than it might seem because `unzip` can’t extract from its standard input, so you can’t chain it with pipes. However, `jar` can extract ZIP archives from its standard input, as can `funzip` (with some limitations).

If `3.zip` *only* contains `4.zip`, or contains `4.zip` as its first member, then `funzip` can be used:

```
unzip -p 1.zip 3.zip | funzip > 4.zip
```

This uses `unzip` to extract `3.zip`’s contents from `1.zip`, piping them to standard output, into `funzip` which extracts `4.zip`’s contents, and writing them to `4.zip`.

`jar` works regardless of the other contents of `3.zip`:

```
unzip -p 1.zip 3.zip | jar x 4.zip
```

This feeds `3.zip`’s contents into `jar`, extracting `4.zip`.

`funzip` is shipped alongside `unzip`; `jar` is part of the Java Development Kit, *e.g.* `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` on Debian 10.